# GroupBy operation using an entire dataframe to group values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 2 dataframes like this...

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,3))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,size=(20,3)))
```

I'd like to find the average of values in `a` for the 4 groups in `b`.

This...

```
a[b==1].sum().sum() / a[b==1].count().sum()
```

...works for doing one group at a time, but I was wondering if anyone could think of a cleaner method.

My expected result is

```
1   -0.088715
2   -0.340043
3   -0.045596
4    0.582136
dtype: float64
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post some expected results? Right now I assume you need 4 values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `stack` then `groupby` two `Series`

```
a.stack().groupby(b.stack()).mean()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a fast numpy solution, use `np.unique` and `np.bincount`:

```
c, d = (a_.to_numpy().ravel() for a_ in [a, b]) 
u, i, cnt = np.unique(d, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

np.bincount(i, c) / cnt
# array([-0.0887145 , -0.34004319, -0.04559595,  0.58213553])
```

To construct a Series, use

```
pd.Series(np.bincount(i, c) / cnt, index=u)

1   -0.088715
2   -0.340043
3   -0.045596
4    0.582136
dtype: float64
```

For comparison, `stack` returns,

```
a.stack().groupby(b.stack()).mean()

1   -0.088715
2   -0.340043
3   -0.045596
4    0.582136
dtype: float64
```

---

```
%timeit a.stack().groupby(b.stack()).mean()
%%timeit
c, d = (a_.to_numpy().ravel() for a_ in [a, b]) 
u, i, cnt = np.unique(d, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
np.bincount(i, c) / cnt

5.16 ms ± 305 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
113 µs ± 1.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Great answer, worth noting that this will fail if you don't have every group from `1-n` present.  I think a fix would be something like `f = np.ones(u.max())`, and then `f[u-1] = c` to divide by that instead

Comment: @user3483203 That's true. In that case we'd have to call bincount on `pd.factorize(b.values.ravel())[0]` and proceed as planned!

Comment: You can safeguard with `return_inverse`... `u, i, c = np.unique(b.to_numpy(), return_inverse=True, return_counts=True); pd.Series(np.bincount(i, a.to_numpy().ravel()) / c, u)`